# ¿Como puedo pasar datos a otro componente en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Como podría hacer para pasar la información que tengo en un estado a otro componente que no tiene que ver nada como en anterior?

Estos son los datos: `const [data, setData] = useState([]);`

pero no puedo pasárselos por `props` porque no hago ninguna llamada desde este componente.

Alguna idea?

Comment: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#:~:text=En%20React%2C%20la%20compartici%C3%B3n%20del,y%20lo%20moveremos%20hacia%20Calculator%20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas crear un estado global, puedes utilizar [redux](https://es.redux.js.org/), o si solo es en un caso en especifico recomiendo usar el [contexto](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) de react, un ejemplo en el que un componente ajeno a otro pueda mostrar o escoder a este utilizando lo ultimo mencionado:

En un archivo llamado context/MyEstadoGlobalContext.js

```
import React from 'react';
const MyEstadoGlobalContext = React.createContext({ mostrar: false, setMostrar: () => {} 
});
export {MyEstadoGlobalContext};
```

En tu app.js:

```
import {MyEstadoGlobalContext} from './context/MyEstadoGlobalContext';
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  const [mostrar, setMostrar] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <MyEstadoGlobalContext.Provider value={{mostar, setMostrar}}>
      <TusComponentes />
    <MyEstadoGlobalContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

De este modo has creado un estado global con valores iniciales, en el componente donde quieras usar o cambiar este estado recomiendo usar los hooks de react:

```
import React from 'react';
import {MyEstadoGlobalContext} from './context/MyEstadoGlobalContext';

const {mostrar, setMostrar} = React.useContext(MyEstadoGlobalContext);
```

Lo anterior lo harias en los lugares en tu proyecto donde necesites el estado global

Con el setMostar cambias el valor de mostrar, por lo que si quieres que se vea actualizas el estado con:

```
setMostrar(true);
```

y el componente que quieras que se vea o no, lo realizas con el operador logico de esta manera:

```
{mostrar && <ComponenteParaEsconder/>}
```

Esta seria la forma mas simple, sin complicarse con redux, te recomiendo leer la documentacion para encontrar mas información, espero haberte ayudado.